# How to give an apache user read/write permissions?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh

How can I give another user on the server the same read/write access permissions just like when I am logged in as root?

Comment: An apache user? You mean the user which apache runs as? Are you sure you want to give the web server full root access? Might it be a specific resource / directory you need it to be able to write to?

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: And yes, this would be for a specific directory

Comment: Make sure that the directory which can be written to isn't configured to execute php or cgi scripts. Most ideally, make it so it can't even be served out by Apache at all. (If you need to re-display the saved information, use a program to fetch and output it.) This will save you a whole lot of pain later.

Answer (score 1):

[chown](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chown1.html) owner:group file. Typically with apache, you want the apache user and group to own very few files, because those accounts are, by necessity, exposed.

Sounds like you really need to [set up some user groups](http://linux.die.net/man/8/groupadd) as well. Staying logged in as root when performing routine tasks is an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: I just want to make sure, I understand. First I add a group: groupadd group name then add the specified user to the group: useradd -G group name username but now I am a little confused about the 'chown' part.

Comment: Chown is "Change Ownership", so you're giving ownership of the files to your group, so that you can control read/write settings at the group level, rather than having to try and control it at the individual user level.